# What do the last two entries of PATH tell you?

Tags: path

I'm still learning how PATH works, what exactly is echo $PATH's output meant to be? What do they tell us?

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly is echo $PATH's output meant to be?

The current path.

> What do the last two entries tell you?

The last two directories on your path.

---

In other words, it's unclear what you're asking. Do you not know what a path is? Are you asking what a particular sequence of special characters mean in the context of a path? What is the explicit path you're asking about?

Answer (score 0):

`$PATH` variable is simply a list of paths that your system automatically checks whenever you run a command on, say your bash terminal.

PATH is a colon `:` (Unix-like) or semi-colon `;` (Windows) separated list.

Whenever you run a command like `ls -lrt`, your system looks for the definition of the command (or function) `ls`. So the definition of the `PATH` variable being established, we can answer your two questions:

> what exactly is echo $PATH's output meant to be

The `$PATH`'s output provides a list of paths.

> What do the last two entries of PATH tell you?

`PATH` is list is of all the paths where your system will look for a command. So the last 2 entries tell you the last 2 paths out of the list.